# Custom context menu in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, contextmenu

I'm trying to create a --seemingly simple-- thing - I would like to be able to create a custom context menu that displays an "X," as a delete option for some elements on my page. Ideally, I would use an external library for this functionality instead of writing another component myself, as I'm attempting to keep this project down to one component file (for reasons I don't have time to put in this question).

I have tried what seems like the perfect library already: https://github.com/isaacplmann/ngx-contextmenu, but it has not worked as intended.

The menu simply appears broken an unusuable, like so:
[image]

The (execute) event attached to the X never fires, and the menu clearly does not display as intended. If anyone has some insight into why this isn't working, this is the code I am currently using:

The element the menu is attached to:

```
<div 
    id="playhead"
    (mousedown)="movePlayheadByMouse()"
    [contextMenu]="deleteMenu"
>
     <span id="playhead-top">&#9930;</span>
     <div id="playhead-line"></div>
</div>
```

The menu itself:

```
<context-menu #deleteMenu>
    <ng-template contextMenuItem (execute)="print('click')">X</ng-template>
</context-menu>
```

The print function (just a log to the console)

```
private print(val : string) : void
{
  console.log(val)
}
```

This ngx-context-menu component doesn't seem like it has a ton of support, so I'm interested in trying other methods. So my questions for you all are:

1) Do you know of any other custom-menu component libraries that will work well for this purpose?

OR

2) Do you know how to change the the Angular Material md-menu trigger to right-click instead of left-click? (which would allow me to use Angular Material's md-menu in this situation?)

Thanks!
Lars

Comment: I do not know the library, however have you tried to bind the output to a function declared in the component?

Comment: if you're referring to the (execute) event that is attached to the contextMenuItem, then yes. It seems like the event is properly bound, but the list is broken in a way that it never catches the click on the menu item.

Comment: Dont know. Maybe there is a conflict with the mousedown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code `(execute)="console.log('click')"` your handler will not work, because in templates, you only have the template scope available (not the global scope, but `console` is in global scope)
So you would need to call a function from your component like
`(execute)="functionFromComponent('click')"`

As for angular material: you could add a manual trigger in this way:

```
class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild(MdMenuTrigger) trigger: MdMenuTrigger;

  someMethod() {
    this.trigger.openMenu();
  }
}
```

And then bind `someMethod()` to a normal click event (and filter out the right-button clicks)

See also: https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview

Comment: You are right, was a faulty example. I have edited the question, and the behavior persists. It would have given me an error if it had tried to call the console.log anyways, but it never did, because the (execute) event is never called.

Comment: Added a suggestion for angular material

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Dunno how I missed that in the docs. That works great for binding the openMenu function to a right-click. However, I have one more question before accepting -- in the docs, it says "Please note that in this case, an mdMenuTriggerFor directive is still necessary to attach the menu to a trigger element in the DOM." Meaning, I still need to bind the mdMenuTriggerFor, which defaults to left-click (and my menu pops up on left click AND right click). Do you know how to finagle it so the menu will not open on left click, ONLY right clicks?

Comment: It should work by preventing the default. So on catching the click event you say: `(click)="someMethod($event)"`  
And then in someMethod you say: `someMethod(event:MouseEvent){event.preventDefault(); event.stopImmediatePropagation(); event.cancleBubble=true;}`

Comment: That particular code doesn't seem to work but I will play around with it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in there, it has to be `cancelBubble`